# Is it possible to run 3+ versions of Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

How might I run 3+ versions of google chrome so I can log into to 2 different google accounts.

More specifically I am looking to have separate icons in the dock for the 3 separate running applications.

How might I run duplicate and or copy versions of the same application.  The following [linked question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/312439/open-two-instances-of-the-same-app-on-mac-os-x/312462#312462) by Mark works for a lot of applications but not for Google Chrome.

It appears the following might work [link](http://josephbeeson.com/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,detail,0&cntnt01articleid=10&cntnt01returnid=17).